# Bootstrap 3 Popover on Button not closing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am running into an issue correctly closing bootstrap 3 popovers using a `<button>` element.

What needs to happen is a popover should close when tapped on a new button or when a click off focus of the existing button.

This works to an extent, by extent I mean the button does hide but is not correctly closed. So if there were buttons `x y z` and I start the instance by click `x` pop over shows correctly.

Now following the next click... say `z`. `x` will hide and `z` will display.

So far so good right?

What happens when I click again on `x` it closes the button fully (no display) and a subsequent click will then show `x`.

In short while click off focus hides the popover it does not fully close it.. Resulting in double clicking a button to display it again, rather than a single click.

For reference see html and js below:

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default videos-popover-button" href="#" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="click" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-content='
<p>{{{description}}}</p>
<form class="video-favorite-mobile">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="" name="favorite" value="favorite">
</form>
<form class="video-queue-mobile">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="" name="queue" value="queue">
</form>
<a href="{{link}}" title="{{name}}" data-video-width="{{width}}" data-video-height="{{height}}" data-description="{{description}}"{{#allow_downloads}}{{#download}} data-download-{{quality}}="{{link}}"{{/download}}{{/allow_downloads}}>watch now</a>'
data-trigger="focus" href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">
<img alt="{{name}}" src="{{thumbnail_large}}">
<div class="video-gallery-single">
    <p>{{{description}}}</p>
</div>
<div class="video-gallery-bottom">
    <form class="video-favorite">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="" name="favorite" value="favorite"
        data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' 
        data-original-title='add to favorites'>
    </form>
    <form class="video-queue">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="" name="queue" value="queue" 
        data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' 
        data-original-title='add to queue'>
    </form>
    <a href="{{link}}" title="{{name}}" data-video-width="{{width}}" data-video-height="{{height}}" data-description="{{description}}"{{#allow_downloads}}{{#download}} data-download-{{quality}}="{{link}}"{{/download}}{{/allow_downloads}}>watch now</a>
</div>
</button>
```

**js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('body').on('click', function (e) {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        }
      });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need `data-trigger="click"`?

If you set `data-trigger` to `focus`, you should be able to dismiss the popover when clicking away from it without any additional javascript (Unless you are looking for a different behavior).

[Bootstrap documentation: Dismissible popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dismiss-on-next-click)

**Edit:**

Your comment:

*"Have attempted with data-trigger="focus" it breaks functionality on mobile browsers specifically iOS."*

You are using a `button` element for your popover trigger. Here is what the docs state:

> Specific markup required for dismiss-on-next-click
>   For proper cross-browser and cross-platform behavior, you must use the `<a>` tag, not the `<button>` tag, and you also must include the `role="button"` and `tabindex` attributes.

Comment: Have attempted with `data-trigger="focus"` it breaks functionality on mobile browsers specifically iOS.

Comment: @sandovalg See the edit to my answer. Does that take care of the mobile browser compatibility?